# how to check the presence of the element on the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

please help solve the problem. i use rails4 + rspec + capybara.

my page has title-element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <title>I am learning Rails</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/albums.self855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
    ......
    .........
    ........
```

rspec test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ImagesController, type: :controller do
  describe "index action" do
    it 'render title-element on root page' do
      visit '/'
      #page.should have_selector 'head title', :visible => false
      page.should have_selector('head title',
                          :text => "Складик картинок")
    end  
  end  
end
```

i run in console:

```
rspec spec
```

but console displays follow error messages:

```
...F

Failures:

  1) ImagesController index action render title-element on root page
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('head title',
       expected to find css "head title" with text "I am learning Rails" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/controllers/images_controller_spec.rb:37:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.94045 seconds (files took 1.95 seconds to load)
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/images_controller_spec.rb:30 # ImagesController index action render title-element on root page
```

Comment: "складик картинок" - so cute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title element isn't displayed on the page so it's not found by capybaras normal finders, however there is a title matcher you can use

```
page.should have_title('your title')
```

Comment: errormessage: Failure/Error: page.should have_title('I am learning Rails')
       expected "" to include "I am learning Rails"

Comment: So its finding a blank title, or no title on the page - Are you sure the correct page is loading? Is your page not loading within Capybara.default_wait_time seconds?  - You can test the timing by putting sleep 10 or something before the page.should have_tittle

Comment: I just noticed that the type of the test is :controller - capybara is really designed for feature tests, please try type: :feature

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated Answer:

Turns out that, there is already a [`have_title` [Capybara RSpec matcher]](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara%2FRSpecMatchers%3Ahave_title) 
which you can use to solve your problem.

```
describe ImagesController, type: :controller do
  describe "index action" do
    it 'render title-element on root page' do
      visit '/'
      expect(page).to have_title "Складик картинок"
    end  
  end  
end
```

Comment: Replacement phrase on 'I am learning Rails' and change selector on 'title' not solved problem. error messages are the same

Comment: You really shouldn't ever need to resort to querying the source, you could pass visible: false to have_selector but the best solution for this is to use the have_title matcher as shown in my answer